# Active Admin CollectionAction route being skipped, action treated as ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, activeadmin

I'm trying to create a collection_action in ActiveAdmin which allows me to rearrange the position after a drop and add. I want to be able to drag and drop the list in the index and have the new positions sent via Ajax through a post request

This is what I have so far:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Subscriber do

collection_action :reorder, :method => :post do 
end

controller do

def reorder

  @item = ResponsiveWeb.find(params[:id])
  @item.position = params[:position]
  @item.saved
  render nothing: true

end


private

def item_params
  params.require(:responsive_web).permit(:id, :position)
end
end
```

These are the routes:

```
 Prefix Verb       URI Pattern                                   Controller#Action
        new_admin_user_session GET        /admin/login(.:format)                        active_admin/devise/sessions#new
            admin_user_session POST       /admin/login(.:format)                        active_admin/devise/sessions#create
    destroy_admin_user_session DELETE|GET /admin/logout(.:format)                       active_admin/devise/sessions#destroy
           admin_user_password POST       /admin/password(.:format)                     active_admin/devise/passwords#create
       new_admin_user_password GET        /admin/password/new(.:format)                 active_admin/devise/passwords#new
      edit_admin_user_password GET        /admin/password/edit(.:format)                active_admin/devise/passwords#edit
                               PATCH      /admin/password(.:format)                     active_admin/devise/passwords#update
                               PUT        /admin/password(.:format)                     active_admin/devise/passwords#update
                    admin_root GET        /admin(.:format)                              admin/dashboard#index
batch_action_admin_admin_users POST       /admin/admin_users/batch_action(.:format)     admin/admin_users#batch_action
             admin_admin_users GET        /admin/admin_users(.:format)                  admin/admin_users#index
                               POST       /admin/admin_users(.:format)                  admin/admin_users#create
          new_admin_admin_user GET        /admin/admin_users/new(.:format)              admin/admin_users#new
         edit_admin_admin_user GET        /admin/admin_users/:id/edit(.:format)         admin/admin_users#edit
              admin_admin_user PATCH      /admin/admin_users/:id(.:format)              admin/admin_users#update
                               PUT        /admin/admin_users/:id(.:format)              admin/admin_users#update
                               DELETE     /admin/admin_users/:id(.:format)              admin/admin_users#destroy
               admin_dashboard GET        /admin/dashboard(.:format)                    admin/dashboard#index
     sort_admin_responsive_web POST       /admin/responsive_webs/:id/sort(.:format)     admin/responsive_webs#sort
 reorder_admin_responsive_webs POST       /admin/responsive_webs/reorder(.:format)      admin/responsive_webs#reorder
```

However when I reorder I get the 404 not found error and when I check the error logs it says, Couldn't find ResponsiveWeb with id=reorder.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To declare a collection action, active admin provide another dsl. Here is an example. You can try that.

```
collection_action :reorder, method: :post do
    # your resources or whatever you need 
end
```

One thing, active admin resource DSL provide a permit_params, so you don't need to declare it on your controller.

Hope this answer helps.

Here is the reference:
http://activeadmin.info/docs/8-custom-actions.html